# Mysql Connect in Delphi. Error handling in TDBX (dbExpress)

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

Here is some code how i check data in my db ( mysql)
Creating ...

```
  CheckThread := TCheckThread.Create(True);
  CheckThread.Start;
```

{ TCheckThread }

```
procedure TCheckThread.Execute;

function AddLine(ALine: string): String;
begin
  CsMemo.Enter;

  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('[' + TimeToStr(Now) + ']SQL Checker ' + ALine);

  CsMemo.Leave;
end;

var
  DateCheckCount: integer;
begin
  GDateCounter := 0;
  FQry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  FSQLConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    FSQLConnection.DriverName := 'MySQL';
    FSQLConnection.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL';
    FSQLConnection.LibraryName := 'dbxmys.dll';
    FSQLConnection.VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';
    FSQLConnection.LoginPrompt := FAlse;

    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['CharacterSet'] := 'utf8';
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['Names'] := 'utf8';
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['ServerCharSet'] := 'utf8';
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['Database'] := dbName;
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['User_Name'] := dbUser;
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['Password'] := dbPass;
    FSQLConnection.Params.Values['HostName'] := dbHost;
    FQry.SQLConnection := FSQLConnection;
    while not self.Terminated do
    begin

      try
        inc(DateCheckCount);
        Foundmini := FAlse;

        FQry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM `' + GlobTableVar + '` WHERE `state`=''Free''';;
        FQry.Prepared := True;
        FQry.Open();
        while not FQry.Eof do
        begin
          GDateFound := True;
          Foundmini := True;
          AddLine('YE');
          Break;
        end;
        FQry.Close;

        if not Foundmini then
        begin
          GDateFound := FAlse;
          AddLine('Check..')
        end;
        try
          if random(6) = 1 then
            Form1.LabelCheckDate.Caption := 'Check #' + inttostr(DateCheckCount);
        except
        end;
        sleep(100);
      except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
          AddLine('[<< REQUEST THREAD DEBUG >>] ' + e.ClassName + ' EwM ' + e.Message);
          FSQLConnection.Close;
          FSQLConnection.Open;
        end;
      end;

    end;
  finally
    FSQLConnection.Free;
    FQry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When my VPS with db is going reboot ( or down) i should hande exeptions and try to reconnect and check data again. But my software is crashing  ( this function used in Thread).

```
version            : 1.0.0.0
compiled with      : Delphi XE4
madExcept version  : 4.0.9
callstack crc      : $5bee8bf0, $af8b0065, $7eedcaab
exception number   : 1
exception class    : TDBXError
exception message  : Can't connect to MySQL server on '82.146.40.149' (10061).
```

Here is call stack

```
thread $57b0 (TCheckThread):
00967d8d +051 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon   10946  +8 TDBXContext.Error
00a14aa2 +10a VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink   824 +21 TDBXMethodTable.RaiseError
00a150fb +013 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink   974  +1 TDBXDynalinkConnection.CheckResult
00a152ec +050 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink  1062  +4 TDBXDynalinkConnection.DerivedOpen
009638b7 +00b VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    8510  +5 TDBXConnection.Open
0095ed36 +0fe VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    6671 +14 TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection
0095ec31 +005 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    6648  +0 TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection
009f85fb +293 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      2487 +53 TSQLConnection.DoConnect
008f01ed +039 VladSoft.exe Data.DB           3483  +8 TCustomConnection.SetConnected
009f9630 +130 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      2870 +32 TSQLConnection.CloneConnection
00a041eb +07b VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      6030  +7 TCustomSQLDataSet.CheckStatement
00a086ca +0a6 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      7550 +10 TSQLQuery.PrepareStatement
00a04082 +0fe VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      5992 +45 TCustomSQLDataSet.SetPrepared
00a45b08 +1b8 VladSoft.exe Unit1             1385 +28 TCheckThread.Execute
004a9c43 +02b VladSoft.exe madExcept                  HookedTThreadExecute
0053d282 +042 VladSoft.exe System.Classes   14548 +12 ThreadProc
0040aad0 +028 VladSoft.exe System           22016 +45 ThreadWrapper
004a9b29 +00d VladSoft.exe madExcept                  CallThreadProcSafe
004a9b8e +032 VladSoft.exe madExcept                  ThreadExceptFrame
77443368 +010 kernel32.dll                             BaseThreadInitThunk
>> created by main thread ($51d4) at:
00a45036 +582 VladSoft.exe Unit1             1193 +48 TForm1.ButtonStartClick

thread $57b0 (TCheckThread), inner exception level 1:
>> TDBXError, Can't connect to MySQL server on '82.146.40.149' (10061)
00967d8d +051 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon   10946  +8 TDBXContext.Error
00a14aa2 +10a VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink   824 +21 TDBXMethodTable.RaiseError
00a150fb +013 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink   974  +1 TDBXDynalinkConnection.CheckResult
00a152ec +050 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXDynalink  1062  +4 TDBXDynalinkConnection.DerivedOpen
009638b7 +00b VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    8510  +5 TDBXConnection.Open
0095ed36 +0fe VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    6671 +14 TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection
0095ec31 +005 VladSoft.exe Data.DBXCommon    6648  +0 TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection
009f85fb +293 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      2487 +53 TSQLConnection.DoConnect
008f01ed +039 VladSoft.exe Data.DB           3483  +8 TCustomConnection.SetConnected
009f9630 +130 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      2870 +32 TSQLConnection.CloneConnection
00a041eb +07b VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      6030  +7 TCustomSQLDataSet.CheckStatement
00a086ca +0a6 VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      7550 +10 TSQLQuery.PrepareStatement
00a04082 +0fe VladSoft.exe Data.SqlExpr      5992 +45 TCustomSQLDataSet.SetPrepared
00a45b08 +1b8 VladSoft.exe Unit1             1385 +28 TCheckThread.Execute
0053d282 +042 VladSoft.exe System.Classes   14548 +12 ThreadProc
0040aad0 +028 VladSoft.exe System           22016 +45 ThreadWrapper
004a9b29 +00d VladSoft.exe madExcept                  CallThreadProcSafe
004a9b8e +032 VladSoft.exe madExcept                  ThreadExceptFrame
77443368 +010 kernel32.dll                             BaseThreadInitThunk
00a45036 +582 VladSoft.exe Unit1             1193 +48 TForm1.ButtonStartClick
```

Can someone help me? I can send some WebMoney to motivate )

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is.  The exception says that it can't connect to the database, and your description says that the database is rebooting at the time.  You can't connect to a database that's not online.

Comment: Yes , but excetion came in main application thread. But, i need to handle excetion in check thread. How exception came in main thread??

Comment: you are trying to reconnect in the exception block and this will lead to an unhandled exception, letting it bubble up to the main thread. Do you not try to reconnect in the except block but set a flag indicating that you need to connect to the database before you can do your  work.

Comment: A second problem is that you are accessing the VCL from another thread (`Form1.LabelCheckDate.Caption`, `AddLine` function, ...), the VCL does not support multhtreading, and you must synchronize all access to it..

Comment: really , Form1.LabelCheckDate.Caption not so critical , but , idea in .close; .open;  - win. Trouble went)))

Comment: yes it is, the VCL is NOT threadsafe! You will run into trouble if you continue writing code like this... Use the `Synchronize` method to access UI/VCL objects.

Comment: I Use Criticall Sections , but i forgot about this label

Comment: Critical sections are not the solution, you must Synchronize with the main thread!

Comment: Hm... starnge ... All time use Synchronize () ?